# ¿Como puedo obtener la propiedad "pass" del mi objeto "user"?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, poo, sequelize.js

Gracias de antemano por su colaboración, tengo el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Problema: userJSON contiene el usuario entero y yo necesito tener acceso a la contraseña pero cuando uso userJSON.pass me devuelve "undefinied"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observaciones: user.pass tambien devuelbe undefinied.

Solución esperada: Acceder al valor del apartado "pass" de mi objeto "user".

Comment: `user` es un array para acceder al `pass` tienes que acceder al array `user[0].pass`

Comment: muchisimas gracias hawks¡¡¡ ya me funciona.

Comment: Por favor, evita subir código en imagenes, puedes copiar y pegar tu código. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo y cay en cuenta despues de formular la pregunta ya he rectificado en mi ultima pregunta aun asi gracias por el consejo Mauricio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer:

```
JSON.stringify('user');
```

estas convirtiendo el JSON en string, y los strings no tienen las propiedades de tu json, para poder acceder a esas propiedades no uses lo que tengas en `JSON.stringify` usa las que acabas de obtener, me explico:

```
.then(user =>{
    var userJSON = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(user[0].pass);
})
```

Accedemos asi por que es un Array

Comment: Si, me lo acaban de decir en otro comentario, aun asi al hacer console.log(user.pass) da undefinied igualmente, hay que usar user[0].pass

Comment: Si por supuesto, se me habia olvidado, tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

Como me informa hawks en un comentario anterior user es un array para acceder al pass hay que acceder al array usando user[0].pass

Comment: NO. Creo que el OP ha puesto el log de la variable `user` que esta como parametro. y crea confusión con la variable `userJSON` y eso si que es un string